# extend inline typescript interface on function

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a pretty simple **React** component which takes a required prop, `active`.

Setting the inline interface for this one prop is quite simple. But now, I need to account for the other types of props that can be passed onto the component.

Luckily, **Native** supplies the props for this element, so I don't have to recreate the interface for it. But I'm struggling to figure out how to *extend* my current inline interface to get it to work.

I've tried this approach:

```
const BarTabName = ({ active, ...props }: { active: boolean; } extends TextProps) => {
    return <Text {...props} />;
};
```

But this just results in the error:

> '?' expected.ts(1005)

If possible, I'm trying to *avoid* creating a separate interface *outside* of the parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an intersection:

```
const BarTabName = ({ active, ...props }: { active: boolean; } & TextProps) => {
```

Comment: So simple, I love it. Thanks!